# Xcode4.5 How to make a share button with SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

In the new xcode4.5 we find the new class SLComposeViewController to share in social networks, I'm reading the Class Reference, but still I don't understand how to make the implementation.

So If you have any idea it would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, I just find how to. Here it is:

You need to add Social.framework to your project.
Add to your file the following #import "Social/Social.h"

You can create 3 type of service:

```
SLServiceTypeTwitter
SLServiceTypeFacebook
SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo
```

Example for Facebook.

```
SLComposeViewController *fbController = 
     [SLComposeViewController 
                 composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=
    ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

       [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

       switch(result){
       case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
       default:
       {
           NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

       }
           break;
       case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
       {
           NSLog(@"Posted....");
           UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent" 
              message:nil
              delegate:nil 
              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
              otherButtonTitles: nil];
           [alert show];
       }
           break;
   }};

   [fbController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.jpg"]];
   [fbController setInitialText:@"The initial text you want to send"];
   [fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"the url you wanna share"]];
   [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
   [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope you find this useful.
If you want for other social network, change SLServiceTypeFacebook for any of the other two.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a drop-in table view cell for implementing the iOS 6 social sharing [here on github](https://github.com/michaelkamprath/iPhoneMK/tree/master/TableViewCells/MKSocialShareTableViewCell). Disclaimer - I am the author.

Answer (score 2):

I have also face this kinds of problem in my last project and I have found [Sample code for SLComposeViewController](http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/social-framework-integration-iphone-sdk-ios/) for the same. I think it will helps you.

Thanks